# Is hair charged with static brittle and susceptible to breakage?

Tags: natural-remedies, electromagnetism, hair

It is said that plastic combs produce static electricity therefore we should use wooden combs.

http://www.joybynature.com/blogs/beauty-style/41263937-6-surprising-benefits-of-using-neem-wood-comb-for-your-tresses

> Hair charged with static is very brittle and highly susceptible to damage due to breakage or exposure to chemicals.

Is it true that plastic combs which generate static electricity in hair can make the hair brittle like the above claim?

Comment: I think you need to expand this a bit: which chemicals? Water is a chemical, air is a chemical, hair itself is a chemical.

Comment: I think that link about external factors like hair dyes, shampoo, pollution, dust. @Sklivvz

Comment: OK, I've read the page, basically what they mean is very generic, also the English itself is not clear ("susceptible to damage due to breakage" and "susceptible to damage due to [...] exposure to chemicals" are two convoluted way of say "susceptible to damage") - i've edited accordingly

Comment: They also seem to ignore the fact that it's quite easy to equalize a static charge produced while brushing one's hair.